# How to control the number of digits when printing numbers?

Tags: python

I need assistance with a code, the final answer needs to be 6 characters, I am asking the person for a number, they can enter the following:

```
 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000
```

What I need is the final number to be 6 characters long so this is the answers for each of the numbers

```
1     => 000001
10    => 000010
100   => 000100
1000  => 001000
10000 => 010000
```

So I need to set the length at 6 digits, enter the number and add "0" to the front until it is 6 digits.

How can I do that?

Additional to this if someone enters 200 I need it to round down to 100 and if they enter 501 it rounds up to 1000; can this also be done?

Answer (score 7):

Okay, two parts:

first, to format a number:

```
"{number:06}".format(number=100)
```

will give you `'000100'`. But before that, we have to round.

**EDIT:** This solution is much more elegant:

```
import math
def rep(number):
    rounded = 10**(math.floor(math.log(number,10)-math.log(0.5,10)))
    return "{number:06}".format(number=int(rounded))
```

Let's see:

```
>>> print rep(100)
000100
>>> print rep(1000)
001000
>>> print rep(501)
001000
>>> print rep(499)
000100
>>> print rep(500)
000100
```

**OLD Version for future reference end educational delight**:

(It's still faster as it doesn't involve any `log` operations)

Here's a neat little trick: `round(501)` will round to the first decimal digit, but `round(501, -1)` will round to the `10^1` digit (so the result is `500.0`), `round(501, -2)` to the `10^2` (the result still being `500.0`), and `round(501, -3)` will round up to 1000.

So we want 500 to be rounded up to 1000, but 53 to be rounded up to 100. Well, here's how we do it:

```
number = 521
rounded = round(number, -len(str(number)))
```

So, since the string describing `number` is three characters long, we round to -3.

However, this rounds up perfectly, but if we're rounding down, it always rounds down to 0. Let's just catch this case:

```
def rep(number):
    rounded = round(number, -len(str(number)))
    if not rounded: # 0 evaluates to False
        rounded = 10**(len(str(number))-1)
    return "{number:06}".format(number=int(rounded))
```

Comment: Everything below **Edit** refers to the second part of the question that got deleted by @Tim (Task: 200 -> 000100, 501 -> 001000)

Comment: I have reverted that part of the question.

Answer (score 4):

[zfill](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) also can help you

```
>>> str(10).zfill(6)
'000010'
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness's sake:

```
>>> for i in range(6):
...   "%06d" % 10**i
```

will print

```
'000001'
'000010'
'000100'
'001000'
'010000'
'100000'
```

Comment: As stated for other answers, the `str.format()` method is highly recommended over the modulo operator for string formatting in new code. This answer should also really just be an edit to another answer.

Comment: The other way round. My reply is from 12:06, the other answers with the modulo operator are from 12:07. I got there first. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> print "%06d" % 1
000001
>>> print "%06d" % 10
000010
>>> print "%06d" % 100
000100
>>> print "%06d" % 1000
001000
>>> print "%06d" % 10000
010000
>>> print "%06d" % 100000
100000
```

[5.6.2. String Formatting Operations](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)

Comment: These are the old string formatting operators. In new code, it is advised to use the new `.format()` method.

Comment: Could you please explain what are the benefits of using the new `.format()` method over using the old string formatting operators in this exact case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Python 2.7 [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) say: "This method of string formatting is the new standard in Python 3, and should be preferred to the % formatting [...] in new code." - the new options are more powerful, more versatile, easier to read and just plain cooler than the old ones. I don't think your answer deserves a downvote, though. So +1 from me to balance that out :)

Comment: Well, and old ones are more compact and familiar to virtually anyone (less head-scratches for the people who will read or maintain your code). I'm not saying one should not use the new options. It's just really good to know the exact reason why you choose one over another in your code. "Documentation says so" is a good reason, but not good enough in many cases. Thanks for the balancing upvote!